# Counting the amount from select data-id

Tags: javascript

There is some JS code which should count an amount from given data-id.
I climbed a lot, but didn’t find an answer how to do it, maybe there’s a person who can help me.

1. Values ​​were repeated only 1 time.
2. The amount was made up of data-id.
3. And the total amount was displayed to be entered in the database.

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>TEST</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <select id="goods" onchange="func()" size="4">
   <option value="-">--</option>
   <option value="milk" dataid="10">milk</option>
   <option value="banana" data-id="12">banana</option>
   <option value="apple" data-id="13">apple</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  Сумма: <span id="summ">0</span>рублей<br>
  <select id="go" onchange="fu()" size="4">
   <option value="-">--</option>
   <option value="milk" dataid="100">milk</option>
   <option value="banana" data-id="120">banana</option>
   <option value="apple" data-id="130">apple</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  Сумма: <span id="sum">0</span>рублей<br>
  Было выбрано:<br>
  <span id="list"></span>
  Общая сумма равна: <span id="test4" name="test4">0</span>рублей<br>
  <script>
   function func() {
       if (goods.selectedIndex) {
           summ.innerText = +summ.innerText + +goods.options[goods.selectedIndex].value;
           list.innerHTML += goods.options[goods.selectedIndex].text + '<br>';
       }
   }
   function fu() {
       if (go.selectedIndex) {
           sum.innerText = +sum.innerText + +go.options[go.selectedIndex].value;
           list.innerHTML += go.options[go.selectedIndex].text + '<br>';
       }
   }
  </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your question and add a bit more explanation what you code is doing. For a start, you could translate the Russian parts inside the code to English, e.g. using https://www.deepl.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not quite sure what you are trying to do but I guess you're trying to display the value of data-id (Summa: [data-id] rub).

You can achieve it like this:

```
summ.innerText = +summ.innerText + +goods.options[goods.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-id');
```